# Sum all x-values and subtract by their mean

Tags: r, sum, standard-deviation, hardcode

I am trying to hard code the formula for standard deviation in R (yes, I know there is a function to do this). This is what I have so far.

```
x = c(1, 6, 2, 7, ... #shortened for clarity
n = length(x)
xBar <- mean(x)
...
StDev = sqrt((sum(x - xBar)) / (n-1))
```

This outputs zero. I am less experienced in R, but I believe my problem is with `sum(x - xBar)`. How can I take the summation of all x-values minus the mean? Thanks!

I would prefer not to write a new function.

Comment: If you show your complete code (not the complete `x`, but at least how you define `xBar`, we can help you figure out where you are wrong. You might also [check your definition of standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Discrete_random_variable) - you need some `^2` in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `^2`. This is your same code with the right formula.

```
x <- c(1, 6, 2, 7)
n <- length(x)
xBar <- mean(x)
...
StDev <- sqrt(sum((x - xBar)^2) / (n - 1))
```

And here you can see it gives the same output as `sd()`.

```
StDev 
[1] 2.94392
sd(x)
[1] 2.94392
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
x = c(1, 6, 2, 7)
sqrt(sum((x-mean(x))^2)/(length(x)-1))
[1] 2.94392
```

As you can see, you have the same output of standard R function `sd`:

```
sd(x)
[1] 2.94392
```

Comment: I would prefer not to write a new function.

Comment: just use the function: sqrt(sum((x-mean(x))^2)/(length(x)-1))